# Caminho relativo para arquivos de fontes em Angular 4

Tags: angular

após criar uma aplicação padrão Angular com o `ng new aplicacao` e inseridas as bibliotecas do PrimeNG, Bootstrap, Fontawesome a aplicação roda normalmente através do `ng server`.

Após rodar o `ng build` e subir a aplicação no servidor tudo funciona desde que a aplicação rode apartir da raiz do domínio (ex: www.abc.com.br). Se a aplicação rodar de uma pasta (ex: www.abc.com.br/appteste) e feitos os ajustes nos caminhos dos .js, a aplicação carrega normalmente mas os arquivos referente as fontes (.woff, .woff2, .ttf, .svg, .eot) ficam sendo buscandos na raiz do domínio com isso apresentando erro 404.

Ou seja, os caminhos dos arquivos citados acima não ficam relativos a pasta que a aplicação está rodando. Como tudo é "juntado" pelo Webpack não sei onde devo alterar para modificar o caminho dos arquivos citados acima.

Alguém sabe como corrigir? Desde já agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Comment: Você pode adicionar o caminho das fontes no arquivo SCSS principal da sua aplicação.

Answer (score -1):

Quando você cria um projeto com ng cli, na raiz do projeto é criado um arquivo: `.angular-cli.json` dentro deste arquivo voce tem o tag `styles e scripts`. Então voce so precisa adicionar os caminhos corretor nesse arquivo, por exemplo:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss",
    "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
    "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
    "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
    "../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css",
    "../node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.css",        
    "app/theme/theme.scss",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js",
    "../node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js"
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, a solução para o caso específico é definir o deploy-url no comando ng build:

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url=/apptest/ --env=dev
```